# JSON parsing error when using Custom Class in AWS Lambda

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am following a AWS Lambda [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-using-predefined-interfaces.html). I have created a Lambda function that takes a custom class as input and outputs another custom class. On entering the test data I am getting a JSON parse error.

```
public class HelloPojo implements RequestHandler<RequestClass, ResponseClass>{

@Override
public ResponseClass handleRequest(RequestClass request, Context context){
    String greetingString = String.format("Hello %s, %s.", request.firstName, request.lastName);
    return new ResponseClass(greetingString);
}
}
```

This is the test input `{ "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" }`. I believe AWS requires input in json format and then it parses it. The following is the custom requestclass object:

```
public class RequestClass {
String firstName;
String lastName;

public RequestClass(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public RequestClass() {
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
```

This is the error message:

```
 "errorMessage": "An error occurred during JSON parsing",
 "errorType": "java.lang.RuntimeException",
 "stackTrace": [],
 "cause": {
     "errorMessage": "org/json/simple/JSONObject",
     "errorType": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError",
```

Here is the responseClass:

```
public class ResponseClass {
String greetings;

public ResponseClass(String greetings) {
    this.greetings = greetings;
}    
public ResponseClass() {
}  
public String getGreetings() {
    return greetings;
}
public void setGreetings(String greetings) {
    this.greetings = greetings;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

Comment: please add ` json-simple-1.1.jar` to the lib. If already exists then clean your workspace and rebuild your project. It will work fine to you. @suku

Comment: This was the problem! As all inputs are json, it should have been included in the lambda build library. Can you please write your comment as the answer?

Comment: I have added this comment as an Answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see your error message that you received as a `json`. you will get your answer.

```
     "errorMessage": "org/json/simple/JSONObject",
     "errorType": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError",
```

> **Error Type** :- `NoClassDefFoundError` Exception means, At runtime when a dependent jar try to link the class named `org.json.simple.JSONObject`. It will not found in your `library`.

### Solution

Please add `json-simple-1.1.jar` to the lib.  If already exists then clean your workspace and rebuild your project. It will work fine to you.